# Invalid JSON parse in AS3. Don't understand why

Tags: json, actionscript-3

My AS3 goes search in my database the infos and displays it in Flash. 
Don't know why but sometimes I've got this error :

```
SyntaxError: Error #1132: Invalid JSON parse input.
    at JSON$/parseCore()
    at JSON$/parse()
    at CineNC3Android_fla::MainTimeline/complete()[CineNC3Android_fla.MainTimeline::frame2:153]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()
```

I'm pretty sure it's due to special character as when I'm deleting lines in my database, it works (as the data is changing every week, I don't know which line are bad, so I have to manually delete each one of them one by one in order to find the error..)

I'd like to understand this error in order to be able to find more quickly what's causing it.

Coud you help me ?

I've exported my database to my desktop in JSON format in order to copy it and paste it here on this forum :

Can you tell me if you see something that could cause this error please ? it drives me crazy.

```
/**
 Export to JSON plugin for PHPMyAdmin
 @version 0.1
 */

// Database 'broussefolie'

// broussefolie.moviedetail_savedToday

[{"id":"1020","movieid":"40567","theTitle":"SOS FANTOMES","movieimage":"http:\/\/www.cinecity.nc\/Content\/images\/AFFICHES\/sos_fantome2.jpg","moviehour":"14:15 - 17:10 - 20:10","trailer":"gmeVnCwrc9c","actorlist":"R&eacute;alis&eacute; par  Paul Feig\navec Melissa McCarthy, Kristen Wiig, Kate McKinnon","movielength":"117 mn","story":"S.O.S. FANTOMES est de retour, revisite et dynamise avec un casting feminin et de tout nouveaux personnages plus hilarants les uns que les autres. Trente ans apres le raz-de-maree planetaire du premier film, le realisateur Paul Feig nous offre sa vision rafraichissante et ultra vitaminee de la comedie surnaturelle, avec la complicite de certaines des personnalites les plus droles du cinema actuel : Melissa McCarthy, Kristen Wiig, Kate McKinnon, Leslie Jones et Chris Hemsworth. Les fantomes n ont qu a bien se tenir !"}, {"id":"1021","movieid":"40564","theTitle":"ELLE","movieimage":"http:\/\/www.cinecity.nc\/Content\/images\/AFFICHES\/elle_reduit.jpg","moviehour":"20h30","trailer":"YqGJtnKZ2vs","actorlist":"R&eacute;alis&eacute; par Paul Verhoeven\navec Isabelle Huppert, Laurent Lafitte, Anne Consigny","movielength":"130 mn","story":"Michele fait partie de ces femmes que rien ne semble atteindre. A la tete dune grande entreprise de jeux video, elle gere ses affaires comme sa vie sentimentale : dune main de fer. Sa vie bascule lorsquelle est agressee chez elle par un mysterieux inconnu. Inebranlable, Michele se met a le traquer en retour. Un jeu etrange sinstalle alors entre eux. Un jeu qui, a tout instant, peut degenerer."}, {"id":"1022","movieid":"40565","theTitle":"SUICIDE SQUAD","movieimage":"http:\/\/www.cinecity.nc\/Content\/images\/AFFICHES\/suicide_squad_reduit.jpg","moviehour":"14h10 - 17h35 - 20h40","trailer":"XfboDbU3xnA","actorlist":"R&eacute;alis&eacute; par David Ayer\navec Margot Robbie, Will Smith, Jared Leto","movielength":"130 mn","story":"C est tellement jouissif d etre un salopard ! Face a une menace aussi enigmatique qu invincible, l agent secret Amanda Waller reunit une armada de crapules de la pire espece. Armes jusqu aux dents par le gouvernement, ces Super-Mechants s embarquent alors pour une mission-suicide. Jusqu au moment ou ils comprennent qu ils ont ete sacrifies. Vont-ils accepter leur sort ou se rebeller"}, {"id":"1023","movieid":"40555","theTitle":"INDEPENDANCE DAY 2 RESURGENCE\u00a0","movieimage":"http:\/\/www.cinecity.nc\/Content\/images\/AFFICHES\/independance_day_2_reduit.jpg","moviehour":"20h35","trailer":"b577i7s2CiM","actorlist":"R&eacute;alis&eacute; par Roland Emmerich\navec Liam Hemsworth, Jeff Goldblum, Bill Pullman","movielength":"121 mn","story":"Nous avons toujours su qu ils reviendraient. La terre est menacee par une catastrophe d une ampleur inimaginable. Pour la proteger, toutes les nations ont collabore autour d un programme de defense colossal exploitant la technologie extraterrestre recuperee. Mais rien ne peut nous preparer a la force de frappe sans precedent des aliens. Seule l ingeniosite et le courage de quelques hommes et femmes peuvent sauver l humanite de l extinction."}, {"id":"1024","movieid":"40548","theTitle":"CONJURING 2  ","movieimage":"http:\/\/www.cinecity.nc\/images\/AFFICHES\/conjuring-2_reduit.jpg","moviehour":"13h45 - 20h25","trailer":"Y3kNhv0Nm_g","actorlist":"R&eacute;alis&eacute; par James Wan            avec Vera Farmiga, Patrick Wilson, Frances O'Connor","movielength":"134 mn","story":"Une nouvelle histoire vraie issue des dossiers d'Ed et Lorraine Warren : l'une de leurs enqu&#234;tes les plus traumatisantes.&lt;br\/&gt;&lt;br\/&gt;Lorraine et Ed Warren se rendent dans le nord de Londres pour venir en aide &#224; une m&#232;re qui &#233;l&#232;ve seule ses quatre enfants dans une maison hant&#233;e par des esprits mal&#233;fiques. Il s'agira d'une de leurs enqu&#234;tes paranormales les plus terrifiantes"}, {"id":"1025","movieid":"40560","theTitle":"INSAISISSABLES 2","movieimage":"http:\/\/www.cinecity.nc\/Content\/images\/AFFICHES\/insaisissables_2_reduit.jpg","moviehour":" 17h25 - 20h15","trailer":"0iGn57DVJIc","actorlist":"R&eacute;alis&eacute; par  Jon M. Chu\navec Jesse Eisenberg, Mark Ruffalo, Woody Harrelson","movielength":"125 mn","story":"Un an apres avoir surpasse le FBI et acquis l admiration du grand public grace a leurs tours exceptionnels, les 4 Cavaliers reviennent ! Pour leur retour sur le devant de la scene, ils vont denoncer les methodes peu orthodoxes d un magnat de la technologie a la tete d une vaste organisation criminelle. Ils ignorent que cet homme d affaire, Walter Marbrya une longueur d avance sur eux, et les conduit dans un piege : il veut que les magiciens braquent l un des systemes informatiques les plus securises du monde. Pour sortir de ce chantage et dejouer les plans de ce syndicat du crime, ils vont devoir elaborer le braquage le plus spectaculaire jamais concu."}, {"id":"1026","movieid":"40551","theTitle":"DE GLACE 5 : LES LOIS DE L'UNIVERS \u00a0","movieimage":"http:\/\/www.cinecity.nc\/images\/AFFICHES\/l_age_de_glac_loi_de_l_univers_reduit.jpg","moviehour":" 13h30 - 15h50 - 17h20 - 20h55","trailer":"9v44tabqvoo","actorlist":"R&eacute;alis&eacute; par Mike Thurmeier, Galen T. Chu            avec Ray Romano, Simon Pegg, John Leguizamo","movielength":"95 mn","story":"La qu&#234;te permanente de Scrat pour attraper son insaisissable noisette le catapulte dans l'espace, o&#249; il d&#233;clenche accidentellement une s&#233;rie d'&#233;v&#233;nements cosmiques qui vont transformer et menacer le monde de l'&#194;ge de Glace. Pour sauver leur peau, Sid, Manny, Diego et le reste de la bande vont devoir quitter leur foyer et embarquer dans une nouvelle aventure pleine de com&#233;die, parcourant de nouvelles terres exotiques et rencontrant une galerie de parsonnages hauts en couleur."}, {"id":"1027","movieid":"40556","theTitle":"LE BGG - LE BON GROS GEANT \u00a0","movieimage":"http:\/\/www.cinecity.nc\/images\/AFFICHES\/le_bon_gros_geant_reduit.jpg","moviehour":"14h20 ","trailer":"aiUo4MCHWBA","actorlist":"R&eacute;alis&eacute; par Steven Spielberg            avec Dany Boon, Mark Rylance, Ruby Barnhill","movielength":"117 mn","story":"Le Bon Gros G&#233;ant ne ressemble pas du tout aux autres habitants du Pays des G&#233;ants. Il mesure plus de 7 m&#232;tres de haut et poss&#232;de de grandes oreilles et un odorat tr&#232;s fin. Il n'est pas tr&#232;s malin mais tout &#224; fait adorable, et assez secret. Les g&#233;ants comme le Buveur de sang et l'Avaleur de chair fra&#238;che, sont deux fois plus grands que lui et aux moins deux fois plus effrayants, et en plus, ils mangent les humains. Le BGG, lui, pr&#233;f&#232;re les schnockombres et la frambouille. &#192; son arriv&#233;e au Pays des G&#233;ants, la petite Sophie, une enfant pr&#233;coce de 10 ans qui habite Londres, a d'abord peur de ce myst&#233;rieux g&#233;ant qui l'a emmen&#233;e dans sa grotte, mais elle va..."}, {"id":"1028","movieid":"40541","theTitle":"LE MONDE DE DORY  ","movieimage":"http:\/\/www.cinecity.nc\/images\/AFFICHES\/le_monde_de_dory_reduit.jpg","moviehour":"13h35 - 15h50 - 18h10","trailer":"yE3VBMHFQQs","actorlist":"R&eacute;alis&eacute; par Andrew Stanton, Angus MacLane            avec Franck Dubosc, Kev Adams, Philippe Lellouche","movielength":"95 mn","story":"Dory, le poisson chirurgien bleu amn&#233;sique, retrouve ses amis Nemo et Marlin. Tous trois se lancent &#224; la recherche du pass&#233; de Dory. Pourra-t-elle retrouver ses souvenirs ? Qui sont ses parents ? Et o&#249; a-t-elle bien pu apprendre &#224; parler la langue des baleines ?"}, {"id":"1029","movieid":"40546","theTitle":"NINJA TURTLES 2  ","movieimage":"http:\/\/www.cinecity.nc\/images\/AFFICHES\/ninja_turtles_2_reduit.jpg","moviehour":"14h15","trailer":"rAkDlbyPuDg","actorlist":"R&eacute;alis&eacute; par Dave Green            avec Megan Fox, Stephen Amell, Noel Fisher","movielength":"112 mn","story":"Michelangelo, Donatello, Leonardo et Raphael sont de retour pour affronter des m&#233;chants toujours plus forts et impressionnants, aux c&#244;t&#233;s d'April O'Neil, Vern Fenwick et d'un nouveau venu, le justicier masqu&#233; hockeyeur Casey Jones. Apr&#232;s son &#233;vasion de prison, Shredder associe ses forces &#224; celles d'un savant fou Baxter Stockman et de deux hommes de main aussi b&#234;tes que costauds, Bebop &amp; Rocksteady. Leur objectif : lancer un plan diabolique pour r&#233;gner sur le monde entier ! Alors que les Ninja Turtles s'appr&#234;tent &#224; d&#233;fier Shredder et son nouveau gang, ils doivent rapidement faire face &#224; une menace tout aussi grande : le c&#233;l&#232;bre Krang !"}, {"id":"1030","movieid":"40571","theTitle":"PETER ET ELLIOT LE DRAGON","movieimage":"http:\/\/www.cinecity.nc\/Content\/images\/AFFICHES\/peter_elliott.jpg","moviehour":"13h50 - 16h15 - 20h00","trailer":"yW9MTo17N9w","actorlist":"R&eacute;alis&eacute; par  David Lowery\navec Oakes Fegley, Bryce Dallas Howard, Robert Redford","movielength":"103 mn","story":"Depuis de longues annees, M. Meacham, un vieux sculpteur sur bois, regale les enfants du coin avec ses histoires sur un feroce dragon qui vivrait au plus profond de la foret voisine. Pour sa fille Grace, garde forestiere de son etat, tout ceci n est que contes a dormir debout\u2026 jusqu au jour ou elle fait connaissance avec Peter. Ce mysterieux petit garcon de 10 ans - qui dit n avoir ni famille ni foyer - assure qu il vit dans les bois avec un dragon geant baptise Elliott. Et la description qu il en fait correspond etonnamment a celui dont parle son pere\u2026 Avec l aide de la jeune Natalie - la fille de Jack, le proprietaire de la scierie -, Grace va tout mettre en oeuvre pour decouvrir qui est vraiment Peter, d ou il vient, et percer le secret de son incroyable histoire\u2026"}, {"id":"1031","movieid":"40559","theTitle":"COMME DES BETES","movieimage":"http:\/\/www.cinecity.nc\/Content\/images\/AFFICHES\/comme_des_betes_reduit.jpg","moviehour":" 13h40 - 16h00 - 18h15","trailer":"CcPNAD-P1Eo","actorlist":"R&eacute;alis&eacute; par Yarrow Cheney, Chris Renaud\navec Philippe Lacheau, Fran\u00e7ois Damiens, Willy Rovelli","movielength":"87 mn","story":"La vie secrete que menent nos animaux domestiques une fois que nous les laissons seuls a la maison pour partir au travail ou a l ecole."}, {"id":"1032","movieid":"40554","theTitle":"TARZAN  ","movieimage":"http:\/\/www.cinecity.nc\/images\/AFFICHES\/tarzan_reduit.jpg","moviehour":"17h50","trailer":"PGBDdZJbC5A","actorlist":"R&eacute;alis&eacute; par David Yates            avec Alexander Skarsg\u00c3\u00a5rd, Margot Robbie, Christoph Waltz","movielength":"110 mn","story":"Apr&#232;s avoir grandi dans la jungle africaine, Tarzan a renou&#233; avec ses origines aristocratiques, r&#233;pondant d&#233;sormais au nom de John Clayton, Lord Greystoke. Il m&#232;ne une vie paisible aupr&#232;s de son &#233;pouse Jane jusqu'au jour o&#249; il est convi&#233; au Congo en tant qu'&#233;missaire du Commerce. Mais il est loin de se douter du pi&#232;ge qui l'attend. Car le redoutable belge Leon Rom est bien d&#233;cid&#233; &#224; l'utiliser pour assouvir sa soif de vengeance et sa cupidit&#233;"}, {"id":"1033","movieid":"40537","theTitle":"WARCRAFT : LE COMMENCEMENT  ","movieimage":"http:\/\/www.cinecity.nc\/images\/AFFICHES\/warcraft_reduit.jpg","moviehour":"20h35","trailer":"InBV7RggnYQ","actorlist":"R&eacute;alis&eacute; par Duncan Jones            avec Travis Fimmel, Toby Kebbell, Paula Patton","movielength":"124 mn","story":"Le pacifique royaume d'Azeroth est au bord de la guerre alors que sa civilisation doit faire face &#224; une redoutable race d'envahisseurs: des guerriers Orcs fuyant leur monde moribond pour en coloniser un autre. Alors qu'un portail s'ouvre pour connecter les deux mondes, une arm&#233;e fait face &#224; la destruction et l'autre &#224; l'extinction. De c&#244;t&#233;s oppos&#233;s, deux h&#233;ros vont s'affronter et d&#233;cider du sort de leur famille, de leur peuple et de leur patrie."}, {"id":"1034","movieid":"40570","theTitle":"STAR TREK SANS LIMITES","movieimage":"http:\/\/www.cinecity.nc\/Content\/images\/AFFICHES\/star_trek_ss_limites.jpg","moviehour":"14h00 - 17h40 - 20h30","trailer":"Y5GLGwOQDbs","actorlist":"R&eacute;alis&eacute; par Justin Lin\navec Chris Pine, Zachary Quinto, Simon Pegg","movielength":"123 mn","story":"Une aventure toujours plus epique de l USS Enterprise et de son audacieux equipage. L equipe explore les confins inexplores de l espace, faisant face chacun, comme la Federation toute entiere, a une nouvelle menace."}, {"id":"1035","movieid":"40558","theTitle":"AMERICAN NIGHTMARE 3 ELECTIONS","movieimage":"http:\/\/www.cinecity.nc\/Content\/images\/AFFICHES\/American_Nighmare_3_reduit.jpg","moviehour":"13h55 - 18h00 - 20h50","trailer":"VJA8JxvjTj0","actorlist":"R&eacute;alis&eacute; par James DeMonaco\navec Frank Grillo, Elizabeth Mitchell, Mykelti Williamson","movielength":"105 mn","story":"Une senatrice americaine se lance dans la course a l election presidentielle en proposant l arret total de la Purge annuelle. Ses opposants profitent alors d une nouvelle edition de cette journee ou tous les crimes sont permis pour la traquer et la tuer..."}, {"id":"1036","movieid":"40568","theTitle":"JASON BOURNE","movieimage":"http:\/\/www.cinecity.nc\/Content\/images\/AFFICHES\/jason_bourne.jpg","moviehour":"14h05 - 17h15 - 20h05","trailer":"euya1zwQ6U0","actorlist":"R&eacute;alis&eacute; par Greengrass\navec Matt Damon, Tommy Lee Jones, Alicia Vikander","movielength":"124 mn","story":"La traque de Jason Bourne par les services secrets americains se poursuit. Des iles Canaries a Londres en passant par Las Vegas..."}, {"id":"1037","movieid":"40569","theTitle":"FOLLES DE JOIE","movieimage":"http:\/\/www.cinecity.nc\/Content\/images\/AFFICHES\/folles_joie.jpg","moviehour":"17h45","trailer":"IDPx5xKcvyY","actorlist":"R&eacute;alis&eacute; par Paolo Virz\u00ec\navec Valeria Bruni Tedeschi, Micaela Ramazzotti, Bob Messini\nCom\u00e9die dramatique - Italie - 2016 - 118 mn - Tous publics - V","movielength":"118 mn","story":"Beatrice est une mythomane bavarde au comportement excessif. Donatella est une jeune femme tatouee, fragile et introvertie. Ces deux patientes de la Villa Biondi, une institution therapeutique pour femmes sujettes a des troubles mentaux, se lient d amitie. Une apres-midi, elles decident de s enfuir bien decidees a trouver un peu de bonheur dans cet asile de fous a ciel ouvert qu est le monde des gens \u00ab sains\u00bb."}]
```

The JSON file is downloadable here if it's not readable on this forum :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5-MjJcEPm3lUHpDWTIxb0NmR1k/view?usp=sharing

---

EDIT

The thing, I don't have a JSON file. I export it in order to show you but in my AS3, the data are directly taken from my database. My code is doing so :

```
var urlReqSearchAll: URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.brousse-en-folie.com/cinenc/searchMovie4.php");
var loader5:URLLoader = new URLLoader();    searchAll();        function searchAll():void { 
            if (contains(list)){
                list.removeChildren();  
            }
            loading.visible=true;
            urlReqSearchAll.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;  
                loader5.load(urlReqSearchAll);
                loader5.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,complete);
        }

        function complete(e:Event):void {

        loading.visible=false;
    addChild(list);
    products = JSON.parse(loader5.data) as Array;
```

}

Comment: Is your url accessible from anywhere? I'm trying to load it in a test project, but get HTTP status 200 and no `COMPLETE` event

Comment: Does `trace(loader5.data)` show JSON without comments?

Comment: Doesn't show anything... The error "Invalid JSON parse input" is popping before the trace.

Comment: Try commenting out `products = JSON.parse(loader5.data) as Array;` and/or `trace(loader5.data);` on the line before

Comment: nothing.. (literally nothing). I type `trace("loader5.data="+loader5.data);` and the output was `loader5.data= `

Comment: then `SyntaxError: Error #1132: Invalid JSON parse input.
 at JSON$/parseCore()
 at JSON$/parse()
 at CineNC3Android_fla::MainTimeline/complete()[CineNC3Android_fla.MainTimeline::frame2:154]
 at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
 at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
 at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121233/discussion-between-www0z0k-and-user5870211).

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON string **without** commented header is parsed OK:
**test.json** file

```
[{"id":"1020","movieid":"40567","theTitle":"SOS FANTOMES","movieimage":"http:\/\/www.cinecity.nc\/Content\/images\/AFFICHES\/sos_fantome2.jpg","moviehour":"14:15 - 17:10 - 20:10","trailer":"gmeVnCwrc9c","actorlist":"R&eacute;alis&eacute; par  Paul Feig\navec Melissa McCarthy, Kristen Wiig, Kate McKinnon","movielength":"117 mn","story":"S.O.S. FANTOMES est de retour, revisite et dynamise avec un casting feminin et de tout nouveaux personnages plus hilarants les uns que les autres. Trente ans apres le raz-de-maree planetaire du premier film, le realisateur Paul Feig nous offre sa vision rafraichissante et ultra vitaminee de la comedie surnaturelle, avec la complicite de certaines des personnalites les plus droles du cinema actuel : Melissa McCarthy, Kristen Wiig, Kate McKinnon, Leslie Jones et Chris Hemsworth. Les fantomes n ont qu a bien se tenir !"}, {"id":"1021","movieid":"40564","theTitle":"ELLE","movieimage":"http:\/\/www.cinecity.nc\/Content\/images\/AFFICHES\/elle_reduit.jpg","moviehour":"20h30","trailer":"YqGJtnKZ2vs","actorlist":"R&eacute;alis&eacute; par Paul Verhoeven\navec Isabelle Huppert, Laurent Lafitte, Anne Consigny","movielength":"130 mn","story":"Michele fait partie de ces femmes que rien ne semble atteindre. A la tete dune grande entreprise de jeux video, elle gere ses affaires comme sa vie sentimentale : dune main de fer. Sa vie bascule lorsquelle est agressee chez elle par un mysterieux inconnu. Inebranlable, Michele se met a le traquer en retour. Un jeu etrange sinstalle alors entre eux. Un jeu qui, a tout instant, peut degenerer."}, {"id":"1022","movieid":"40565","theTitle":"SUICIDE SQUAD","movieimage":"http:\/\/www.cinecity.nc\/Content\/images\/AFFICHES\/suicide_squad_reduit.jpg","moviehour":"14h10 - 17h35 - 20h40","trailer":"XfboDbU3xnA","actorlist":"R&eacute;alis&eacute; par David Ayer\navec Margot Robbie, Will Smith, Jared Leto","movielength":"130 mn","story":"C est tellement jouissif d etre un salopard ! Face a une menace aussi enigmatique qu invincible, l agent secret Amanda Waller reunit une armada de crapules de la pire espece. Armes jusqu aux dents par le gouvernement, ces Super-Mechants s embarquent alors pour une mission-suicide. Jusqu au moment ou ils comprennent qu ils ont ete sacrifies. Vont-ils accepter leur sort ou se rebeller"}, {"id":"1023","movieid":"40555","theTitle":"INDEPENDANCE DAY 2 RESURGENCE\u00a0","movieimage":"http:\/\/www.cinecity.nc\/Content\/images\/AFFICHES\/independance_day_2_reduit.jpg","moviehour":"20h35","trailer":"b577i7s2CiM","actorlist":"R&eacute;alis&eacute; par Roland Emmerich\navec Liam Hemsworth, Jeff Goldblum, Bill Pullman","movielength":"121 mn","story":"Nous avons toujours su qu ils reviendraient. La terre est menacee par une catastrophe d une ampleur inimaginable. Pour la proteger, toutes les nations ont collabore autour d un programme de defense colossal exploitant la technologie extraterrestre recuperee. Mais rien ne peut nous preparer a la force de frappe sans precedent des aliens. Seule l ingeniosite et le courage de quelques hommes et femmes peuvent sauver l humanite de l extinction."}, {"id":"1024","movieid":"40548","theTitle":"CONJURING 2  ","movieimage":"http:\/\/www.cinecity.nc\/images\/AFFICHES\/conjuring-2_reduit.jpg","moviehour":"13h45 - 20h25","trailer":"Y3kNhv0Nm_g","actorlist":"R&eacute;alis&eacute; par James Wan            avec Vera Farmiga, Patrick Wilson, Frances O'Connor","movielength":"134 mn","story":"Une nouvelle histoire vraie issue des dossiers d'Ed et Lorraine Warren : l'une de leurs enqu&#234;tes les plus traumatisantes.&lt;br\/&gt;&lt;br\/&gt;Lorraine et Ed Warren se rendent dans le nord de Londres pour venir en aide &#224; une m&#232;re qui &#233;l&#232;ve seule ses quatre enfants dans une maison hant&#233;e par des esprits mal&#233;fiques. Il s'agira d'une de leurs enqu&#234;tes paranormales les plus terrifiantes"}, {"id":"1025","movieid":"40560","theTitle":"INSAISISSABLES 2","movieimage":"http:\/\/www.cinecity.nc\/Content\/images\/AFFICHES\/insaisissables_2_reduit.jpg","moviehour":" 17h25 - 20h15","trailer":"0iGn57DVJIc","actorlist":"R&eacute;alis&eacute; par  Jon M. Chu\navec Jesse Eisenberg, Mark Ruffalo, Woody Harrelson","movielength":"125 mn","story":"Un an apres avoir surpasse le FBI et acquis l admiration du grand public grace a leurs tours exceptionnels, les 4 Cavaliers reviennent ! Pour leur retour sur le devant de la scene, ils vont denoncer les methodes peu orthodoxes d un magnat de la technologie a la tete d une vaste organisation criminelle. Ils ignorent que cet homme d affaire, Walter Marbrya une longueur d avance sur eux, et les conduit dans un piege : il veut que les magiciens braquent l un des systemes informatiques les plus securises du monde. Pour sortir de ce chantage et dejouer les plans de ce syndicat du crime, ils vont devoir elaborer le braquage le plus spectaculaire jamais concu."}, {"id":"1026","movieid":"40551","theTitle":"DE GLACE 5 : LES LOIS DE L'UNIVERS \u00a0","movieimage":"http:\/\/www.cinecity.nc\/images\/AFFICHES\/l_age_de_glac_loi_de_l_univers_reduit.jpg","moviehour":" 13h30 - 15h50 - 17h20 - 20h55","trailer":"9v44tabqvoo","actorlist":"R&eacute;alis&eacute; par Mike Thurmeier, Galen T. Chu            avec Ray Romano, Simon Pegg, John Leguizamo","movielength":"95 mn","story":"La qu&#234;te permanente de Scrat pour attraper son insaisissable noisette le catapulte dans l'espace, o&#249; il d&#233;clenche accidentellement une s&#233;rie d'&#233;v&#233;nements cosmiques qui vont transformer et menacer le monde de l'&#194;ge de Glace. Pour sauver leur peau, Sid, Manny, Diego et le reste de la bande vont devoir quitter leur foyer et embarquer dans une nouvelle aventure pleine de com&#233;die, parcourant de nouvelles terres exotiques et rencontrant une galerie de parsonnages hauts en couleur."}, {"id":"1027","movieid":"40556","theTitle":"LE BGG - LE BON GROS GEANT \u00a0","movieimage":"http:\/\/www.cinecity.nc\/images\/AFFICHES\/le_bon_gros_geant_reduit.jpg","moviehour":"14h20 ","trailer":"aiUo4MCHWBA","actorlist":"R&eacute;alis&eacute; par Steven Spielberg            avec Dany Boon, Mark Rylance, Ruby Barnhill","movielength":"117 mn","story":"Le Bon Gros G&#233;ant ne ressemble pas du tout aux autres habitants du Pays des G&#233;ants. Il mesure plus de 7 m&#232;tres de haut et poss&#232;de de grandes oreilles et un odorat tr&#232;s fin. Il n'est pas tr&#232;s malin mais tout &#224; fait adorable, et assez secret. Les g&#233;ants comme le Buveur de sang et l'Avaleur de chair fra&#238;che, sont deux fois plus grands que lui et aux moins deux fois plus effrayants, et en plus, ils mangent les humains. Le BGG, lui, pr&#233;f&#232;re les schnockombres et la frambouille. &#192; son arriv&#233;e au Pays des G&#233;ants, la petite Sophie, une enfant pr&#233;coce de 10 ans qui habite Londres, a d'abord peur de ce myst&#233;rieux g&#233;ant qui l'a emmen&#233;e dans sa grotte, mais elle va..."}, {"id":"1028","movieid":"40541","theTitle":"LE MONDE DE DORY  ","movieimage":"http:\/\/www.cinecity.nc\/images\/AFFICHES\/le_monde_de_dory_reduit.jpg","moviehour":"13h35 - 15h50 - 18h10","trailer":"yE3VBMHFQQs","actorlist":"R&eacute;alis&eacute; par Andrew Stanton, Angus MacLane            avec Franck Dubosc, Kev Adams, Philippe Lellouche","movielength":"95 mn","story":"Dory, le poisson chirurgien bleu amn&#233;sique, retrouve ses amis Nemo et Marlin. Tous trois se lancent &#224; la recherche du pass&#233; de Dory. Pourra-t-elle retrouver ses souvenirs ? Qui sont ses parents ? Et o&#249; a-t-elle bien pu apprendre &#224; parler la langue des baleines ?"}, {"id":"1029","movieid":"40546","theTitle":"NINJA TURTLES 2  ","movieimage":"http:\/\/www.cinecity.nc\/images\/AFFICHES\/ninja_turtles_2_reduit.jpg","moviehour":"14h15","trailer":"rAkDlbyPuDg","actorlist":"R&eacute;alis&eacute; par Dave Green            avec Megan Fox, Stephen Amell, Noel Fisher","movielength":"112 mn","story":"Michelangelo, Donatello, Leonardo et Raphael sont de retour pour affronter des m&#233;chants toujours plus forts et impressionnants, aux c&#244;t&#233;s d'April O'Neil, Vern Fenwick et d'un nouveau venu, le justicier masqu&#233; hockeyeur Casey Jones. Apr&#232;s son &#233;vasion de prison, Shredder associe ses forces &#224; celles d'un savant fou Baxter Stockman et de deux hommes de main aussi b&#234;tes que costauds, Bebop &amp; Rocksteady. Leur objectif : lancer un plan diabolique pour r&#233;gner sur le monde entier ! Alors que les Ninja Turtles s'appr&#234;tent &#224; d&#233;fier Shredder et son nouveau gang, ils doivent rapidement faire face &#224; une menace tout aussi grande : le c&#233;l&#232;bre Krang !"}, {"id":"1030","movieid":"40571","theTitle":"PETER ET ELLIOT LE DRAGON","movieimage":"http:\/\/www.cinecity.nc\/Content\/images\/AFFICHES\/peter_elliott.jpg","moviehour":"13h50 - 16h15 - 20h00","trailer":"yW9MTo17N9w","actorlist":"R&eacute;alis&eacute; par  David Lowery\navec Oakes Fegley, Bryce Dallas Howard, Robert Redford","movielength":"103 mn","story":"Depuis de longues annees, M. Meacham, un vieux sculpteur sur bois, regale les enfants du coin avec ses histoires sur un feroce dragon qui vivrait au plus profond de la foret voisine. Pour sa fille Grace, garde forestiere de son etat, tout ceci n est que contes a dormir debout\u2026 jusqu au jour ou elle fait connaissance avec Peter. Ce mysterieux petit garcon de 10 ans - qui dit n avoir ni famille ni foyer - assure qu il vit dans les bois avec un dragon geant baptise Elliott. Et la description qu il en fait correspond etonnamment a celui dont parle son pere\u2026 Avec l aide de la jeune Natalie - la fille de Jack, le proprietaire de la scierie -, Grace va tout mettre en oeuvre pour decouvrir qui est vraiment Peter, d ou il vient, et percer le secret de son incroyable histoire\u2026"}, {"id":"1031","movieid":"40559","theTitle":"COMME DES BETES","movieimage":"http:\/\/www.cinecity.nc\/Content\/images\/AFFICHES\/comme_des_betes_reduit.jpg","moviehour":" 13h40 - 16h00 - 18h15","trailer":"CcPNAD-P1Eo","actorlist":"R&eacute;alis&eacute; par Yarrow Cheney, Chris Renaud\navec Philippe Lacheau, Fran\u00e7ois Damiens, Willy Rovelli","movielength":"87 mn","story":"La vie secrete que menent nos animaux domestiques une fois que nous les laissons seuls a la maison pour partir au travail ou a l ecole."}, {"id":"1032","movieid":"40554","theTitle":"TARZAN  ","movieimage":"http:\/\/www.cinecity.nc\/images\/AFFICHES\/tarzan_reduit.jpg","moviehour":"17h50","trailer":"PGBDdZJbC5A","actorlist":"R&eacute;alis&eacute; par David Yates            avec Alexander Skarsg\u00c3\u00a5rd, Margot Robbie, Christoph Waltz","movielength":"110 mn","story":"Apr&#232;s avoir grandi dans la jungle africaine, Tarzan a renou&#233; avec ses origines aristocratiques, r&#233;pondant d&#233;sormais au nom de John Clayton, Lord Greystoke. Il m&#232;ne une vie paisible aupr&#232;s de son &#233;pouse Jane jusqu'au jour o&#249; il est convi&#233; au Congo en tant qu'&#233;missaire du Commerce. Mais il est loin de se douter du pi&#232;ge qui l'attend. Car le redoutable belge Leon Rom est bien d&#233;cid&#233; &#224; l'utiliser pour assouvir sa soif de vengeance et sa cupidit&#233;"}, {"id":"1033","movieid":"40537","theTitle":"WARCRAFT : LE COMMENCEMENT  ","movieimage":"http:\/\/www.cinecity.nc\/images\/AFFICHES\/warcraft_reduit.jpg","moviehour":"20h35","trailer":"InBV7RggnYQ","actorlist":"R&eacute;alis&eacute; par Duncan Jones            avec Travis Fimmel, Toby Kebbell, Paula Patton","movielength":"124 mn","story":"Le pacifique royaume d'Azeroth est au bord de la guerre alors que sa civilisation doit faire face &#224; une redoutable race d'envahisseurs: des guerriers Orcs fuyant leur monde moribond pour en coloniser un autre. Alors qu'un portail s'ouvre pour connecter les deux mondes, une arm&#233;e fait face &#224; la destruction et l'autre &#224; l'extinction. De c&#244;t&#233;s oppos&#233;s, deux h&#233;ros vont s'affronter et d&#233;cider du sort de leur famille, de leur peuple et de leur patrie."}, {"id":"1034","movieid":"40570","theTitle":"STAR TREK SANS LIMITES","movieimage":"http:\/\/www.cinecity.nc\/Content\/images\/AFFICHES\/star_trek_ss_limites.jpg","moviehour":"14h00 - 17h40 - 20h30","trailer":"Y5GLGwOQDbs","actorlist":"R&eacute;alis&eacute; par Justin Lin\navec Chris Pine, Zachary Quinto, Simon Pegg","movielength":"123 mn","story":"Une aventure toujours plus epique de l USS Enterprise et de son audacieux equipage. L equipe explore les confins inexplores de l espace, faisant face chacun, comme la Federation toute entiere, a une nouvelle menace."}, {"id":"1035","movieid":"40558","theTitle":"AMERICAN NIGHTMARE 3 ELECTIONS","movieimage":"http:\/\/www.cinecity.nc\/Content\/images\/AFFICHES\/American_Nighmare_3_reduit.jpg","moviehour":"13h55 - 18h00 - 20h50","trailer":"VJA8JxvjTj0","actorlist":"R&eacute;alis&eacute; par James DeMonaco\navec Frank Grillo, Elizabeth Mitchell, Mykelti Williamson","movielength":"105 mn","story":"Une senatrice americaine se lance dans la course a l election presidentielle en proposant l arret total de la Purge annuelle. Ses opposants profitent alors d une nouvelle edition de cette journee ou tous les crimes sont permis pour la traquer et la tuer..."}, {"id":"1036","movieid":"40568","theTitle":"JASON BOURNE","movieimage":"http:\/\/www.cinecity.nc\/Content\/images\/AFFICHES\/jason_bourne.jpg","moviehour":"14h05 - 17h15 - 20h05","trailer":"euya1zwQ6U0","actorlist":"R&eacute;alis&eacute; par Greengrass\navec Matt Damon, Tommy Lee Jones, Alicia Vikander","movielength":"124 mn","story":"La traque de Jason Bourne par les services secrets americains se poursuit. Des iles Canaries a Londres en passant par Las Vegas..."}, {"id":"1037","movieid":"40569","theTitle":"FOLLES DE JOIE","movieimage":"http:\/\/www.cinecity.nc\/Content\/images\/AFFICHES\/folles_joie.jpg","moviehour":"17h45","trailer":"IDPx5xKcvyY","actorlist":"R&eacute;alis&eacute; par Paolo Virz\u00ec\navec Valeria Bruni Tedeschi, Micaela Ramazzotti, Bob Messini\nCom\u00e9die dramatique - Italie - 2016 - 118 mn - Tous publics - V","movielength":"118 mn","story":"Beatrice est une mythomane bavarde au comportement excessif. Donatella est une jeune femme tatouee, fragile et introvertie. Ces deux patientes de la Villa Biondi, une institution therapeutique pour femmes sujettes a des troubles mentaux, se lient d amitie. Une apres-midi, elles decident de s enfuir bien decidees a trouver un peu de bonheur dans cet asile de fous a ciel ouvert qu est le monde des gens \u00ab sains\u00bb."}]
```

**Main.as**

```
[Embed(source = "../jsons/test.json", mimeType = "application/octet-stream")] public var test:Class;
public function Main() {
    trace(JSON.parse(new test()));
}
```

outputs

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

as expected.

So if I understand the issue correctly removing comments should help